# Using ArcPy in own installed Python?

Tags: arcpy, python, installation

Before I installed ArcGIS , I have installed python2.7 with many modules and then the ArcGIS installed another python2.7 in other folder.

Now I want to use the arcpy in own old installed python,because I dont want to install these modules again.

I have added Paths in the `PYTHONPATH` system environment variable included

`D:\software\arcgis10.2\python2.7\ArcGIS10.2\Lib`
`D:\software\arcgis10.2\python2.7\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages`

and add paths in the `PATH` included

`D:\software\arcgis10.2\arcgis10.2\Desktop10.2\arcpy`
`D:\software\arcgis10.2\arcgis10.2\Desktop10.2\bin`

However, when I import `arcpy` ,I still encountered errors `ImportError: No module named arcpy`

Comment: *Now I want to use the module(arcpy) in my own installed python* - Why?  What exactly are you trying to do, and why can't you do it using the ArcGIS python install?

Comment: I find it's just easier to use the ArcGIS install for all my python needs, so if there's something additional that you're doing that can't make use of that install I think it would be useful to have the information included here.  You can [edit] your question to add additional info.

Comment: @Midavalo I have installed many modules in old python. Then the arcgis installed new python and I have to installed these modules again. So,I want to use arcpy in old python

Comment: You *can't* use arcpy in an older than supported Python. "Unsupported" doesn't do justice to the inadvisability of that configuration.